# Do I really have to nullify all the members in move constructor/move asigment or just pointers?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I'm having really hard time to learn nullifying the "other" object, I've just read the whole big article about move semantics [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx) and I'm disappointed because it does not cover **nullifying.**

Please explain me do we really need to nullify all the members of "other" or just pointers that are pointing to dynamically allocated memory?

Why would we care about nullifying the members (of other object) that are not on the heap? any good reason?

Comment: I don't think "nullify" is a word. Maybe it's a legal term or something.

Comment: Cant say exactly but i guess since heap allocation is done by user its his duty to free it. Rest of the other members within object will be freed by OS when it gets such an instruction when the object is actually deleted . Nullify is done so as to overcome dangling pointers which can create a problem when used wrongly by programmers . It makes sure that deferenceing a nulified pointer will actually result in core dump and is easy to find the bug through cores generated

Comment: @KerrekSB: "nullify" is certainly a word.... and not slang slang specific to any industry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've moved from the object, its destructor is still going to get called once it's cleaned up. This means that it needs to know whether or not it should free resources it owns, and hence they need to be nullified (or whatever you call it!) so pointers don't get double-deleted etc.

Comment: But destructor frees only heap alocated data, not stack alocated data, and I saw many examples on the net nullifying not only pointer to the heap but all the members. Why all? This is realy whired and I can't understand why plain data should be nullifiyied.

Comment: @codekiddy You only need to make sure the destructor of the moved-from object won't clean up what it shouldn't. You can do that by making stuff null and make sure the destructor is prepared for that, or you can do that by using a `bool empty;` member and wrapping the destructor with `if(!empty) {}`. It doesn't matter how, as long as you don't end up destroying the same resource twice.

Comment: Not correct. Destructors are called for objects allocated on the stack as well. Generally you wouldn't need to nullify plain data members unless they're going to be used somehow in the destructor. It's not really incorrect to do that, just probably unnecessary.

Comment: So that means that only members that are mentioned in the destructor must be nullifyied while other members which are not mentioned in destructor are save to retain it's values so we don't have to nullify them. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: My thought was that all that happens to an object after it's moved from is that it gets destroyed - the whole point of the move constructor is that the compiler knows that the object can be destructively moved. Hence the destructor is the thing I'd be worried about after the move. I can't say 100% though; I haven't used C++0x extensively since there's no sign of it appearing at work yet.

Comment: Thanks, actally I just found an topic talking about this "problem" [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/70b009a8-d472-49e2-a1fb-bab755dd4866) obviously not all the member must be nulifyied :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to leave the object that has been moved from in a *valid state*. I take this to mean that no use of that object should result in undefined behaviour. In practice, that means not leaving pointers pointing to released memory. I can imagine there could be other scenarios, such as if the object is holding onto any other resources (open sockets, files, whatever).

Comment: Yes, but why to nullify plain data like ints for example? int is just an int on the stack, destructor won't touch that int at all, so why would we care about nullifying that int?

Comment: You shouldn't care about the int. Unless your design is such that someone can come along, check the int, and based on its result, do something that according to your design it shouldn't. But this is a far fetched scenario. You can't nullify values.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you actually mean this in case of just constructor or even in case of normal pointers allocated dynamically .

But Nullyfing a pointer saves it from being termed as `Dangling pointer` as it points to null after the memory allocated for it is free. Further use of these pointers and dereferencing those will lead to core dumps which are easy to locate than when not done so . Not doing so can give unexpected results and lead to core dumps hard to find and even data corruption.

In short You should take care of only nullyfing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, "it depends".

The moved-from object will still have to be destroyed, or possibly assigned a new value. You have to leave it in a state where these operations will work.

If you have "stolen" pointers to dynamic data, you will probably have to assign null to the original pointers so they can be deleted. If one of the integer members holds the size of the object pointed to, you might have to zero that (to be consistent with the null pointer). Other values can possibly be left as they are.